# Html table to JSON : including radio button checked values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I have a html table in which there are :

- **rowspans**
- radio buttons of **different groups in merged cells**

The table looks like :

```html
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Data1</th>
        <th>Data2</th>
        <th>Data3</th>
        <th>Data4</th>
        <th>Data5</th>
        <th>Data6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="0" name="typeOf0"> <span>Option 1</span> </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="typeOf0" checked=""> <span>Option 2</span> </label>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">12313</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">5</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">8</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="0" name="typeOf1" checked=""> <span>Option 1</span> </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="typeOf1"> <span>Option 2</span> </label>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">46456</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">3</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">2</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">9</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

> Let's say there is a button:

```html
<button class="btn conPhy" id="convert06Phy">Convert</button>
```

What I want is, when I click the button the table should be converted to a JSON Format like this below where in radio buttons in each row :

- **0 = Option 1 is checked and**
- **1 = Option 2 is checked**

```js
    var data = [{
      "Data1": 1,
      "Data2": 12313,
      "Data3": [5,0,0],
      "Data4": [0,8,0],
      "Data5": [0,0,3],
      "Data6": 50
    },
    {
      "Data1": 0,
      "Data2": 46456,
      "Data3": [3,0,0],
      "Data4": [0,2,0],
      "Data5": [0,0,9],
      "Data6": 110
    }];
```

How should I approach to solve this with **jQuery**?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I know before I helped you correctly, ah forget it, but please make sure to do your try first or post the code that you have done yet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right. One should do proper research before asking a question. I have gone through this library https://www.github.developerdan.com/table-to-json/ but the owner of this library said it cannot convert a table to JSON including radio buttons. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @AhmedAli I am trying, Bhai. Tried with this one  https://github.developerdan.com/table-to-json but couldn't get a way to understand how should I add support for random radio buttons.

Comment: I hope , I will help you but I guess you don't want col-span depending on `json`. I will only do that `json` will create radio button groups and select selected.

Comment: @AhmedAli Bhai, see there are no colspans. I just want to convert the table to json and if there is any radio button in any cell, i want to store the selected value of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#convert").click(function(){
    console.clear();
    ths = []; // Init a dummy array to capture the headers
    jQuery("#sfl th").each(function(){
        let th = jQuery(this).text();
      if(th){
      ths.push(jQuery.trim(th)) // store the headers that will be used as key later
      }
    })
    data = [];
    var totalRows = jQuery("#sfl tr:gt(0)").length; // calculate the length of the table rows

    for(var i =0; i<totalRows; i=i+3){ // run a for loop on length of the table rows with step of 3 i.e row span
        temp = {}; // init a dummy object
              temp[ths[0]] = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+")  td:eq(0)").find("input:checked").val(); // start with i+1 because 0 belongs to header row

      temp[ths[1]] = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+") td:eq(1)").text();
  // you can loop the next three using for if you want. 
      values = [];
      value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+") td:eq(2)").text();
            values.push(value);
      for(j = 1; j < 3; j++){
       value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(j+i+1)+") td:eq(0)").text();
       values.push(value)
      }
            temp[ths[2]] = values;

            values = [];
      value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+") td:eq(3)").text();
            values.push(value);
      for(j = 1; j < 3; j++){
       value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(j+i+1)+") td:eq(1)").text();
       values.push(value)
      }
            temp[ths[3]] = values;

values = [];
      value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+") td:eq(4)").text();
            values.push(value);
      for(j = 1; j < 3; j++){
       value = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(j+i+1)+") td:eq(2)").text();
       values.push(value)
      }
            temp[ths[4]] = values;          
       // till this

            temp[ths[5]] = jQuery("#sfl tr:eq("+(i+1)+") td:eq(5)").text();


      data.push(temp); get the collected data

    }


    console.log(data); // view the output in console.log
  })

});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8e3t54g/1/)